# Pyplot- expanding the x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

This is the code that I have used to produce the following output:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np

    xedges = [27.5, 35, 42.5, 50, 57.5, 65, 72.5, 80, 87.5, 95, 102.5, 110, 117.5, 125, 132.5, 140, 147.5, 155, 162.5]
    yedges = [0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200, 220, 240, 260, 280, 300, 320, 340, 360, 380]
    H = pd.read_stata ('R:/data.dta')
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(H, cmap="nipy_spectral", interpolation='bilinear', origin='low',extent=[xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]])
```

[image]

The x-axis on the graph looks extremely compressed. I want to be able to produce the same graph but with a wider x-axis, how could I do this?

I suspect it has something to do with the 'extent' parameter, but I'm unsure of how to do it.

Comment: Stretch the figure?

Comment: But I also want to be able to observe more granularity between x-axis values.

Comment: Do you mean to stretch the x axis but have it cover the same range in which case figsize is your friend, or do you wish to extend the range in which case xlim is similarly friendly.

Comment: I want to stretch out the graph so it covers the same range. I just want more space between the x-axis ticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just figured this out. The solution was to set the aspect ratio to 'auto' in the code as follows:

```
plt.imshow(H, cmap="nipy_spectral", interpolation='bilinear', origin='low',aspect = 'auto', extent=[xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]])
```